# How to configure Yahoo Kafka-manager?

Tags: apache-kafka, sbt, yahoo-kafka-manager

I want to setup `kafka-manager` by Yahoo. While starting with this command:  `./sbt clean dist`. I'm getting below console message but nothing else. I've also downloaded the required jar(sbt-launcher). Please help.

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.9 ...
```

Comment: Under which directory did you try to run `./sbt clean dist`?

Comment: I'm doing this this under the kafka-manager-master directory where the sbt file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires internet connection on your machine where you want to build it, because there are lot more scala dependencies to be downloaded up on build command (./sbt clean dist). It has taken around 2 hrs to download all the jars.And finally it works for me.

Comment: This is exactly what I've told you.

Comment: Yes. thanks a lot for your time.But for first time I've tried to build it without internet connect in my machine and there were no no failure messages like failed to download or something else instead it was showing like processing. That made me to wait for long time and raise the question here. Anyway thanks again it was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is nothing wrong with this. Allow some time and the build will proceed normally, once the dependencies are downloaded. To verify this, you can run `sbt` in verbose mode using `-v` option and you will be able to see dependencies which are being downloaded and are not visible.

Instead of running `sbt` in verbose mode, you can also have a look at the update log by running

```
$ tail -f $HOME/.sbt/boot/update.log
```

Comment: Hi Giorgos, can you please confirm does it requires internet service while running build command, because I dont have internet. For the first time I run it, the console asked me download sbt-launcher jar only and I did for it.

Comment: Yes, it should require internet connection.

Comment: And while using verbose mode (-v) 
[residual] arg = 'clean'
[residual] arg = 'dist'
No extra sbt options have been defined
Detected sbt version 0.13.9
Using default jvm options
Detected Java version: 1.8.0_77
# Executing command line:
/home/uniconnect/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java
-Xss2m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-jar
/home/uniconnect/.sbt/launchers/0.13.9/sbt-launch.jar
warn
"set javaHome in ThisBuild := Some(file("/home/uniconnect/jdk1.8.0_77"))"
info
clean
dist
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.9 ...

Comment: So what is the other way if I don't have internet on my server. Is there any way to manually download the required jars?

Comment: You can build the project on another machine which has access to internet and then move the files on your server. You can also check this article https://github.com/sbt/sbt/wiki/User-Stories:--Offline-mode-and-Dependency-Locking in order to check how to set your sbt into offline mode.

Comment: How can we use it for kafka latest version. kafka v 2.0.0? Does it supports?

Comment: @RajashekharMeesala Yes, it should.